# how to call the variables using function together with loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Im quite new to Python and not familiar with the syntax. So currently,im trying to create a very simple hangman game such that the game will randomly choose the word from word list based on the category that is chosen. However, im not sure how to call the variables(WORD_LIST 1 2 and 3) that i have created using function together with loop..

```
import random, sys
from typing import List

# TODO try to load these from a text file
WORD_LIST1 = ["tables","ladders","chairs"]
WORD_LIST2=  ["chicken","dog","cat"]
WORD_LIST3=  ["basketball","soccer","rugby"]


category=["objects","animals","sports"]
def category():
    categoryname = input("Please select a category\n").strip()
    for x in range(3):
        if categoryname=category(x)

            #How to create function to call the word_list 1 2 and 3 here?

        else:
            print("wrong category")
            tryagain=input("Choose another category\n").strip()
```

Comment: What do you mean by call the variables? If you just want to print the word list you can use global WORD_LIST1 inside function to access it.
Also you don't need a for loop to check user input, just do:
       if categoryname in category:

Comment: Please clarify what you want to do. Your code is malformed – it is wrongly indented and some parts aren't valid Python (e.g. ``if categoryname=category(x)``). What do you mean by calling variables? One can call *functions*, and it is possible to pass variables *into* a function as arguments. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: @SubhashR because the only thing i have learnt so far is calling variables from functions so i wasnt sure what other options are avaliable though..

Comment: @MisterMiyagi oh ya, i have forgotten python is indentation sensitive, my bad...Yeah to your 2nd question..

Comment: You can learn more about dictionaries in python to solve such challenges. Added a sample in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. This version of program will keep prompting the user to only enter the allowed category values if the user enters a wrong category. Finally it will print a random entry from that category when an allowed category is input by the user.

```
import random

# Store the category and values into a dictionary
categories = {
    "objects": ["tables", "ladders", "chairs"],
    "animals": ["chicken", "dog", "cat"],
    "sports": ["basketball", "soccer", "rugby"]

}

def category():
    print("Please enter category name: ")
    response = ''

    #Keep prompting the user to only enter allowed category values
    while response.lower() not in categories:
        # join(map(str, list((*categories,))) is used for retrieving the key values i.e. the category values from the dictionary "categories" and then join them as a string in order to display the allowed values back to the user
        response = input(' One among the following [%s] : \n' % ', '.join(map(str, list((*categories,)))))

    if response in categories:
        word_list = categories.get(response)
        # Print a random value from the chosen category
        print(random.choice(word_list))

# Call the function
category()
```

Comment: sorry if you don't mind can i ask  what is .join(map(str, list((*categories,))))?

Comment: join(map(str, list((*categories,))) is used for retrieving the key values i.e. the category values from the dictionary "categories" and then join them as a string in order to display the allowed values back to the user

Answer (score 2):

This is where you can make use of dictionary in python. See the below code

```
category_lists = {
    "objects": ["tables", "ladders", "chairs"],
    "animals": ["chicken", "dog", "cat"],
    "sports": ["basketball", "soccer", "rugby"]

}

def category():
    categoryname = input("Please select a category\n").strip()
    if categoryname in category_lists:
        word_list = category_lists.get(categoryname)
        # do what ever you want with the list
        SECRET_WORD = random.choice(word_list)
        print(SECRET_WORD)
    else:
        print("wrong category")
```

You can load the categories from a JSON file or some external source if you need.

Comment: when i type one of the category list like "objects", nothing happens. So here can i assume that is it a valid response?(Like it means programme  has chosen a random word from this category for hangman game?)

Comment: i tried to use the category_list that you have created and randomize it using SECRET_WORD = random.choice(category_lists) and i got the keyerror:1 which im not sure what i have done wrong

Comment: word_list = category_lists.get(categoryname) gets the list of words for particular categoryname. You have to get a random choice from this list. I Have updated answer with a sample code.

Answer (score -2):

You can simply pass it as regular arguments. No extra thing is required. You can read about unpacking variable arguments but that I believe is a little advanced and you dont need it.

here you can do e.g.

```
processUserGuesses(WORD_LIST1)
```